# How to get a random integer in Freemarker template?

Tags: random, integer, freemarker

Is it possible to generate a random integer in [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) template?

Answer (score 3):

Freemarker does not provide a random number generator at the moment.
You can implement a naive random number generator using the time ( .now ) as a seed, but it should never be a critical part of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random integer in Java and pass this integer to the Freemarker template.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation of random generation using time, like Kayhadrin suggests. I didn't have the time to test if it actually works, but may be of help to someone.

http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.fi/2011/07/howto-generate-random-integer-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Another option would actually be to create your own [Freemarker method](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html) and inject it into the data model.

Here is an example on how to do this in Java 8:

```
public String generate(Map<String, Object> data, String templateLocation) throws IOException, TemplateException {
    try (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
        Template template = configuration.getTemplate(templateLocation);
        data.put("uuid", (TemplateMethodModelEx) (list) -> UUID.randomUUID());
        Random r = new Random();
        // Adding method for generation of random number
        data.put("randomNumber", (TemplateMethodModelEx) (list) -> r.nextInt(200));
        template.process(data, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

In the Freemarker template you will then be able to use this method using:

```
${randomNumber()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just threw a relatively random number generator together. It takes the milliseconds of `.now?long` and multiplies it by your seed **salt** (in this case 7) and divides by three. In my case I only needed 5 numbers but it can go up to the 13 digits of the milliseconds for the day. Or more if you want to add more multipliers, addends, etc.

```
<#function randomNumber salt>
    <#local str= .now?long />
    <#assign str = (str * salt)/3 />
    <#return str[(str?string?length-5)..]/>
</#function>


<#assign rnd = randomNumber(7)/>
```

If you don't want a **salt**, you can just remove the parameter and hard code it for the **salt** variable in the calculation and just call `randomNumber()`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to add a random image out of some set to each listed item.
So get a seed, and then rotate that seed in some way.

```
<#assign photos>
  DSC_0005.jpg
  DSC_0008.jpg
  DSC_0013.jpg
  DSC_0020.jpg
</#assign>
<#assign photos = photos?split('\\n', 'rmc') >
<#assign nextRandom = .now?string["HHmmssSSS"]?number>

<#list posts as post>
     <div class="banner divider" style="background-image: url(photos/panoramas/${photos[nextRandom % photos?size]});"></div>
     <#assign nextRandom = nextRandom * 13 % 104729>
</#list>
```

I chose `nextRandom = nextRandom * 13 % 104729`, but I bet that's very not-random in statistical terms. Also make sure that 104729 is larger than the collection you iterate.

See [Freemarker special variables reference](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_specvar.html).

---

Better approach, at least for HTML, would be to put that collection to JavaScript and pick it from there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var photos = [ <#list photos as photo> '${photo}', </#list> ];
    var randomPhoto = photos[Math.floor(photos.length * Math.random())];
</script>
```

See e.g. [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) at MDN.